# Passing scripts to ssh and invoking the shebang

Tags: ssh, unix, stdin

I have scripts in several languages which I pipe to [`ssh`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) to have them invoked on other hosts. For shell scripts I'm able to do this:

```
ssh < /path/to/script.sh
```

For scripts in other languages however, I find myself having to do this:

```
ssh python - < /path/to/script.py
```

Locally I can run the scripts without specifying the interpreter, due to their [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) lines, and executable bits.

How can I have `ssh` execute scripts regardless of language by invoking the appropriate interpreter from the shebang? Is there something I can have `ssh` invoke regardless of scripts language to do this?

### Update0

The `ssh` invocation is part of yet another script which I am developing, this is strictly specific to coding and not server management.

Answer (score 3):

Could you invoke a command that reads it's input into a temporary file and executes that? Something like

```
ssh user@host '{ F=$(mktemp /tmp/scripts.XXXXXX); cat > $F ; chmod +x $F; $F; rm $F }' < foo.py
```

Comment: curious as to why you have the whole command in `{}`?

Comment: Overcorrection? :-)

Comment: No comprendo, please explain :P

Comment: It doesn't seem to be required in this case (though this might be a bash-ism), but I'm used to wrapping groups that need descriptor redirection in `{}`. Like people who use too many commas, correct the spelling of already correct words (thereby misspelling them), etc. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  The shebang line is recognized by the OS when it's `exec`-ing a file.  When you're piping it over ssh, you're just sending commands to the shell (/bin/sh) or whatever other command you specified should be run.

The only way to have the remote server recognize the shebang is to copy the files to the remote server and set the execute bit.

You could fake it by writing a wrapper around ssh that looks for a shebang line in standard input to determine what command to run, or by doing some trickery to make non-sh scripts run under sh, like the classic tcl idiom

```
# \
exec tclsh "$0" "$@"
```

(I don't know the equivalent for other languages)

Comment: that's a nice idea